# Running flask app on DigitalOcean: should I keep the ssh console open all the time?

Tags: python, ssh, flask, digital-ocean

I created a droplet that runs a flask application. My question is when I ssh into the droplet and restart the apache2 server, do I have to keep the console open all the time (that is I should not shut down my computer) for the application to be live?

What if I have a dynamic application that runs scripts in the background, do I have to keep the console open all the time for the dynamic parts to work?

P.S:
there's a similar question in SO about a NodeJs app but some parts of the answer they provided are irrelevant to my Flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "screen" command to mantain the sesion open.

please see https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just went through the link to Screen: it's pretty straightforward how to create a screen an all but I still cannot see how to maintain the session/screen open even when I shut down the computer?

Comment: Ctrl-A -> Ctrl-D will exit the screen and leave it open

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is not a good practice to use remote computers for the development stage unless you don't have an other option. If you want to make your application available after logging out from the ssh console, screen works, but it still a workaround.

I would suggest taking a look at this [great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to daemonize flask applications with Gunicorn+Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't keep the console on, the app will still running after you close **the console on your computer**. But you may need to set a log to monitor it.